# Detect beat and play (wav) file in a synchronised manner

Tags: python, audio-processing, beat-detection

I am trying my hands at Audio Processing in python with [this](http://archive.gamedev.net/archive/reference/programming/features/beatdetection/index.html) Beat Detection algorithm. I have implemented the first (non-optimized version) from the aforementioned article. While it prints some results, I have no way to detect whether it works with some accuracy or not as I do not know how to play sound with it.

Currently, I am using `Popen` to asynchronously start my media player with the song before going into the computation loop, but I am not sure if this strategy works and is giving synchronous results.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import scipy.io.wavfile, numpy, sys, subprocess

# Some abstractions for computation
def sumsquared(arr):
    sum = 0
    for i in arr:
            sum = sum + (i[0] * i[0]) + (i[1] * i[1])

    return sum

if sys.argv.__len__() < 2:
    print 'USAGE: wavdsp <wavfile>'
    sys.exit(1)

numpy.set_printoptions(threshold='nan')
rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read(sys.argv[1])


# Beat detection algorithm begin 
# the algorithm has been implemented as per GameDev Article
# Initialisation
data_len = data.__len__()
idx = 0
hist_last = 44032
instant_energy = 0
local_energy = 0
le_multi = 0.023219955 # Local energy multiplier ~ 1024/44100


# Play the song
p = subprocess.Popen(['audacious', sys.argv[1]])

while idx < data_len - 48000:
    dat = data[idx:idx+1024]
    history = data[idx:hist_last]
    instant_energy = sumsquared(dat)
    local_energy = le_multi * sumsquared(history)
    print instant_energy, local_energy
    if instant_energy > (local_energy * 1.3):
            print 'Beat'

    idx = idx + 1024
    hist_last = hist_last + 1024 # Right shift history buffer

 p.terminate()
```

What modification/additions can I make to the script in order to get audio output and the algorithm (console) output in a time synchronised manner? i.e When console outputs result for a particular frame, that frame must be playing on the speakers.

Comment: You can rewrite `sumsquared` as one line: `return (arr**2).sum()`.  This will push all of  those computations down into C code and will probably be much faster.

Answer (score 5):

## Working beat detection code (NumPy / PyAudio)

If you are using NumPy this code might help. It assumes the signal (read with PyAudio) is 16-bit wide Int. If that is not the case change or remove the signal.astype() and adjust the  normalization-divider (max int16 here).

```
class SimpleBeatDetection:
    """
    Simple beat detection algorithm from
    http://archive.gamedev.net/archive/reference/programming/features/beatdetection/index.html
    """
    def __init__(self, history = 43):
        self.local_energy = numpy.zeros(history) # a simple ring buffer
        self.local_energy_index = 0 # the index of the oldest element

    def detect_beat(self, signal):

        samples = signal.astype(numpy.int) # make room for squares
        # optimized sum of squares, i.e faster version of (samples**2).sum()
        instant_energy = numpy.dot(samples, samples) / float(0xffffffff) # normalize

        local_energy_average = self.local_energy.mean()
        local_energy_variance = self.local_energy.var()

        beat_sensibility = (-0.0025714 * local_energy_variance) + 1.15142857
        beat = instant_energy > beat_sensibility * local_energy_average

        self.local_energy[self.local_energy_index] = instant_energy
        self.local_energy_index -= 1
        if self.local_energy_index < 0:
            self.local_energy_index = len(self.local_energy) - 1

        return beat
```

The PyAudio examples for wav read or mic record will give you the needed signal data. Create a NumPy array efficiently with `frombuffer()`

```
data = stream.read(CHUNK)
signal = numpy.frombuffer(data, numpy.int16)
```

Comment: Implemented this, and tested it by clapping in front of my microphone. False positive rate was very high. Maybe my expectations were too high and I could tweak it to improve, but just noting it isn't a robust, out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: I know that this is an old question, but did anyone ever managed to improve this example? I have the same issues as @Oddthinking has. I tried to improve it and am still trying but without luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

### A Simpler, Non-Realtime Approach

I'm not optimistic about synchronizing console output with realtime audio.  My approach would be a bit simpler.  As you read through the file and process it, write the samples out to a new audio file.  Whenever a beat is detected, add some hard-to-miss sound, like a loud, short sine tone to the audio you're writing.  That way, you can aurally evaluate the quality of the results.

Synthesize your beat indicator sound:

```
def testsignal(hz,seconds=5.,sr=44100.):
    '''
    Create a sine wave at hz for n seconds
    '''
    # cycles per sample
    cps = hz / sr
    # total samples
    ts = seconds * sr
    return np.sin(np.arange(0,ts*cps,cps) * (2*np.pi))

signal = testsignal(880,seconds = .02)
```

In your `while` loop, add the testsignal to the input frame if a beat is detected, and leave the frame unaltered if no beat is detected. Write those frames out to a file and listen to it to evaluate the quality of the beat detection.

This is the approach used by the [aubio](http://aubio.org/) library to evaluate beat detection results.  See the documentation [here](http://aubio.org/aubioonset.html).  Of particular interest is the documentation for the `--output` command line option:

> Save results in this file. The file will be created on the model of
>   the input file. Results are marked by a very short wood-block sample.

### Optimization

Since numpy is already a dependency, use its capabilities to speed up your algorithm.  You can rewrite your `sumsquared` function as:

```
def sumsquared(arr):
    return (arr**2).sum()
```

Getting rid of the Python for-loop and pushing those calculations down into C code should give you a speed improvement.

Also, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4936620/1015178) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8070349/1015178) to get an idea of how you might vectorize the local to instantaneous energy comparisons in the `while` loop, using the `numpy.lib.stride_tricks` method.

Answer (score 0):

A good bet would be to try portaudio (pyaudio) to get the data live, then you should be able to see if it matches.

Here's a nice example using fft from the mic with pyaudio:

http://www.swharden.com/blog/2010-03-05-realtime-fft-graph-of-audio-wav-file-or-microphone-input-with-python-scipy-and-wckgraph/