# How to implement maxpool: taking a maximum on sliding window on image or tensor

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, conv-neural-network, array-broadcasting

**In short:** I am looking for a simple `numpy` (maybe oneliner) implementation of `Maxpool` - maximum on a window on `numpy.narray` for all location of the window across dimensions.

**In more details:** I am implementing a convolutional neural network ("CNN"), one of the typical layers in such a network is `MaxPool` layer (look for example [here](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/)). Writing 
`y = MaxPool(x, S)`, `x` is an input `narray` and `S` is a parameter,  using pseudocode, the output of the `MaxPool` is given by:

```
     y[b,h,w,c] = max(x[b, s*h + i, s*w + j, c]) over i = 0,..., S-1; j = 0,...,S-1.
```

That is, `y` is `narray` where the value at indexes `b,h,w,c` equals the maximum  taken over the window of size `S x S` along the second and the third dimension of the input `x`,  the window "corner" is placed at the indexes `b,h,w,c`.

**Some additional details:** The network is implemented using `numpy`. CNN has many "layers" where output of one layer is the input to the next layer. The input to a layers are `numpy.narray`s called  "tensors". In my case tensors are  4-dimensional `numpy.narray`'s, `x`. That is `x.shape` is a tuple `(B,H,W,C)`. Each size of dimensions changes after the tensor is process by a layer, for example the input to layer `i= 4` can have size `B = 10, H = 24, W = 24, C = 3`, while the output, aka input to `i+1` layer has `B = 10, H = 12, W = 12, C = 5`. As indicated in the comments the size after application of `MaxPool` is `(B, H - S + 1, W - S + 1, C)`.

**For a concreteness:** if I use

```
import numpy as np

y = np.amax(x, axis = (1,2))
```

where `x.shape` is say `(2,3,3,4)` this will give me what I want but for a degenerate case where the window I am maximizing over is of the size `3 x 3`,   the size of the second and third dimension of `x`, which is not exactly what I want.

Comment: So, the output would be of shape : `(B,H-S+1,W-S+1,C)`, right?

Comment: @Divakar Yes, you are right, the output depends on how many times you can fit in the sliding window

Comment: [`scipy.ndimage.maximum_filter1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.maximum_filter1d.html) implements an O(n) algo (independent of window size)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution using `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` to create sliding windows resulting in a `6D` array of shape : `(B,H-S+1,W-S+1,S,S,C)` and then simply performing max along the fourth and fifth axes, resulting in an output array of shape : `(B,H-S+1,W-S+1,C)`. The intermediate `6D` array would be a view into the input array and as such won't occupy anymore memory. The subsequent operation of `max` being a reduction would efficiently utilize the sliding `views`.

Thus, an implementation would be -

```
# Based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/41850409/3293881
def patchify(img, patch_shape):
    a, X, Y, b = img.shape
    x, y = patch_shape
    shape = (a, X - x + 1, Y - y + 1, x, y, b)
    a_str, X_str, Y_str, b_str = img.strides
    strides = (a_str, X_str, Y_str, X_str, Y_str, b_str)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(img, shape=shape, strides=strides)

out = patchify(x, (S,S)).max(axis=(3,4))
```

Sample run -

```
In [224]: x = np.random.randint(0,9,(10,24,24,3))

In [225]: S = 5

In [226]: np.may_share_memory(patchify(x, (S,S)), x)
Out[226]: True

In [227]: patchify(x, (S,S)).shape
Out[227]: (10, 20, 20, 5, 5, 3)

In [228]: patchify(x, (S,S)).max(axis=(3,4)).shape
Out[228]: (10, 20, 20, 3)
```

Comment: for non-overlapping patches, i.e, for `(a, ((X-x)/x)+1, (Y-y/y)+1, x, y, b)` or simply `(a, X/x, Y/y, x, y, b)`, what strides do I use? Is there a simple way to correlate conv stride (1,2,3.., window_size or full strides) with the strides used by numpy as_strided?

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran Might be simpler to use scikit-image's view_as_blocks I would think.