# as_strided: Linking stepsize (strides of conv2d) with as_strided strides parameter

Tags: python, numpy, conv-neural-network, stride

I found that for generating `(X - x + 1, Y - y + 1)` patches of size `(x,y)` from `(X,Y)` with stride 1, image requires us to give strides parameter as `img.strides * 2` or `img.strides + img.strides`. *I don't know how they quickly compute this knowing the no. of strides in conv2d*

But what should I do to get `((X-x)/stride)+1, ((Y-y)/stride)+1` patches of same size from same sized image with `stride` stride?

---

From this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41850409/3125070) *with slight modification, with channels and number of images placed in front*

```
def patchify(img, patch_shape):
    a,b,X, Y = img.shape                # a images and b channels
    x, y = patch_shape
    shape = (a, b, X - x + 1, Y - y + 1, x, y)
    a_str, b_str, X_str, Y_str = img.strides
    strides = (a_str, b_str, X_str, Y_str, X_str, Y_str)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(img, shape=shape, strides=strides)
```

I can see that it creates a sliding window with size (x,y) and stride 1 (move 1 pixel to the right and move 1 pixel down). I have trouble correlating the strides parameter which `as_strided` uses and the strides we usually use for conv2d.

**How do I add a parameter to the above function that computes `as_strided` strides parameter?**

```
def patchify(img, patch_shape, stride):    # stride=stepsize in conv2d eg: 1,2,3,...
    a,b,X,Y = img.shape                    # a images and b channels
    x, y = patch_shape
    shape = (a,b,((X-x)/stride)+1, ((Y-y)/stride)+1, x, y)
    strides = ???                          # strides for as_strided
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(img, shape=shape, strides=strides)
```

img is 4d `(a, b, X, Y)`

- `a`=no.of images,
- `b`=no.of channels,
- `(X,Y)` = width and height

*Note*: By `stride in conv2d` I mean `stepsize` *Unfortunately this is also called stride*.

*Note 2*: Since `stepsize` will usually be the same on both axes, in the code I provided, I've provided only one parameter, however used it for both dimensions.

**Playground:**
What goes in for `strides` [here](https://trinket.io/python3/bacc739649). I have it running for `stepsize=1` [here](https://trinket.io/python3/c85d12135a). I noticed that it might not work from the link but it works when pasted in new [playground](https://trinket.io/library/trinkets/create?lang=python3).

This should give a clear idea of what I need:

```
[[ 0.5488135   0.71518937  0.60276338  0.54488318]
 [ 0.4236548   0.64589411  0.43758721  0.891773  ]
 [ 0.96366276  0.38344152  0.79172504  0.52889492]
 [ 0.56804456  0.92559664  0.07103606  0.0871293 ]]

# patch_size = 2x2
# stride = 1,1

[[[[ 0.5488135   0.71518937]
   [ 0.4236548   0.64589411]]

  [[ 0.71518937  0.60276338]
   [ 0.64589411  0.43758721]]

  [[ 0.60276338  0.54488318]
   [ 0.43758721  0.891773  ]]]


 [[[ 0.4236548   0.64589411]
   [ 0.96366276  0.38344152]]

  [[ 0.64589411  0.43758721]
   [ 0.38344152  0.79172504]]

  [[ 0.43758721  0.891773  ]
   [ 0.79172504  0.52889492]]]


 [[[ 0.96366276  0.38344152]
   [ 0.56804456  0.92559664]]

  [[ 0.38344152  0.79172504]
   [ 0.92559664  0.07103606]]

  [[ 0.79172504  0.52889492]
   [ 0.07103606  0.0871293 ]]]]

# stride = 2,2

[[[[[[ 0.5488135   0.71518937]
     [ 0.4236548   0.64589411]]

    [[ 0.60276338  0.54488318]
     [ 0.43758721  0.891773  ]]]


   [[[ 0.96366276  0.38344152]
     [ 0.56804456  0.92559664]]

    [[ 0.79172504  0.52889492]
     [ 0.07103606  0.0871293 ]]]]]]

# stride = 2,1

[[[[ 0.5488135   0.71518937]
   [ 0.4236548   0.64589411]]

  [[ 0.71518937  0.60276338]
   [ 0.64589411  0.43758721]]

  [[ 0.60276338  0.54488318]
   [ 0.43758721  0.891773  ]]]

 [[[ 0.96366276  0.38344152]
   [ 0.56804456  0.92559664]]

  [[ 0.38344152  0.79172504]
   [ 0.92559664  0.07103606]]

  [[ 0.79172504  0.52889492]
   [ 0.07103606  0.0871293 ]]]]
```

Comment: What's the input array shape?

Comment: So, you are looking for non-overlapping patches, right? What would be the output array shape with respect to input array shape?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for non overlapping patches too _when the patch_size on each dimension is equal to the stride_. But I'm looking for a function that will accept strides as input, so we can give it any stride, which in this case I would give it the same as patch_size[0]

Comment: @Divakar what strides should be given for non-overlapping patches?

Comment: I think you are confusing between the strides that we get from `img.strides` and your input parameter `stride`. Those are two different things. Your `stride` I am sensing is more like stepsize. A sample case would be nice to clear things up.

Comment: You're right, by strides in conv2d I mean stepsize. I understand and see them as two different things, but I don't know how to link them as in why for stepsize=1 we use strides=img.strides*2 for 2d images as mentioned in the first part of the question

Comment: @Divakar *what `strides` for `as_strided` should be given for non-overlapping patches _or stepsize=patch_size in each dim_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
def patchify(img, patch_shape, stepsize_x=1, stepsize_y=1): 
    strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
    x, y = patch_shape    
    p,q = img.shape[-2:]    
    sp,sq = img.strides[-2:]

    out_shp = img.shape[:-2] + (p-x+1,q-y+1,x,y)
    out_stride = img.strides[:-2] + (sp,sq,sp,sq)

    imgs = strided(img, shape=out_shp, strides=out_stride)
    return imgs[...,::stepsize_x,::stepsize_y,:,:]
```

Sample runs -

1] Input :

```
In [156]: np.random.seed(0)

In [157]: img = np.random.randint(11,99,(2,4,4))

In [158]: img
Out[158]: 
array([[[55, 58, 75, 78],
        [78, 20, 94, 32],
        [47, 98, 81, 23],
        [69, 76, 50, 98]],

       [[57, 92, 48, 36],
        [88, 83, 20, 31],
        [91, 80, 90, 58],
        [75, 93, 60, 40]]])
```

2] Output - Case #1 :

```
In [159]: patchify(img, (2,2), stepsize_x=1, stepsize_y=1)[0]
Out[159]: 
array([[[[55, 58],
         [78, 20]],

        [[58, 75],
         [20, 94]],

        [[75, 78],
         [94, 32]]],


       [[[78, 20],
         [47, 98]],

        [[20, 94],
         [98, 81]],

        [[94, 32],
         [81, 23]]],


       [[[47, 98],
         [69, 76]],

        [[98, 81],
         [76, 50]],

        [[81, 23],
         [50, 98]]]])
```

3] Output - Case #2 :

```
In [160]: patchify(img, (2,2), stepsize_x=2, stepsize_y=1)[0]
Out[160]: 
array([[[[55, 58],
         [78, 20]],

        [[58, 75],
         [20, 94]],

        [[75, 78],
         [94, 32]]],


       [[[47, 98],
         [69, 76]],

        [[98, 81],
         [76, 50]],

        [[81, 23],
         [50, 98]]]])
```

4] Output - Case #3 :

```
In [161]: patchify(img, (2,2), stepsize_x=2, stepsize_y=2)[0]
Out[161]: 
array([[[[55, 58],
         [78, 20]],

        [[75, 78],
         [94, 32]]],


       [[[47, 98],
         [69, 76]],

        [[81, 23],
         [50, 98]]]])
```

Comment: maybe i should have defined stepsize clearly. I understood from the above code. even for stepsize=1 it would be non-overlapping and hence true stepsize will be 2 which is the patch size. So, from your POV, my problem is always overlapping while we can calculate non-overlapping patches by giving stepsize=patch_size. _assuming patch size is same in both dimensions_

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran I would need a sample case.

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran Updated solution.

Comment: You should repost your original proposal as well @Divakar to show alternatives and allow people to compare and contrast the approach with and without the use of as_strided.

Comment: @NaN My original one assumed non-overlapping case, which  won't work given the edits and comments made by OP thereafter as it was mentioned as overlapping. So, just replaced everything. I guess if someone is looking for a non-overlapping case that original post could help them, but not applicable here anymore.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, as_strides is designed to always return with stepsize=1 (overlapping) and the trick is to filter the ones we want from the array returned to get stepsize>1

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran You got it.