# Numpy.split with overlapping matrixes?

Tags: python, numpy, split, overlap

Is it possible to use [`numpy.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) to split a numpy.ndarray with overlapping pieces.

Example:

Given a numpy.ndarray of shape (3,3) and I want to split it into ndarray, of shape (1,1) which by

```
numpy.split((3,3),(1,1)) = [(1,1),(1,1),(1,1)]
```

But what if i wanted numpy.ndarrays of shape (3,2) , would it be able to generate a list with length 2 with overlapping numpy.ndarrays?

as such:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsyCv.png)

Comment: Could you specify what you'd like the output to look like, given an input like `np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))`? (also: why do you want this?)  My first thought would be `np.lib.index_tricks.as_strided`

Comment: @mdurant I added an example with image. I am using overlapping as a way of generating a smooth transition between the first set, and the second set. 
Ps. I also corrected the wanted shape from (2,2) to (3,2)... Might have caused confusion..

Comment: I've flagged my own post. found solution somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you want to see, but this might answer your question:

With input:

```
> arr = np.arange(9, dtype='int64').reshape((3, 3))

array([[0, 1, 2],
      [3, 4, 5],
      [6, 7, 8]])


> np.lib.index_tricks.as_strided(arr, (2, 2, 2, 2), (24, 8, 24, 8), True)

array([[[[0, 1],
         [3, 4]],
        [[1, 2],
         [4, 5]]],
       [[[3, 4],
         [6, 7]],
        [[4, 5],
         [7, 8]]]])
```

Interestingly, there are no copies of the data here. Note that the values to `as_strided` are only accurate for 8-byte values and a 3x3 input. You could get them from the existing shape/strides of the input.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit on the parameter you've entered in the function?

Comment: To properly parametrize, bits could be picked up from this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16788733/3293881