Implementing 2D sliding window over np.array without overlaps (tiling, mean pooling)
I'm trying to implement 2D sliding window of cubic shape (k,k), to so I can iterate over a frame (n,m,3) and calculate the mean over the pixel values in each window.
I want each iteration, that the window will present the next slide without any overlapping values;
i.e. given this matrix:
[
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7 ,8],
  [9, 10, 11, 12],
  [13, 14, 15, 16]
 ]

and for k = 2
I'll have something as follows:
 [
  [1, 2],
  [5, 6]
 ]

and the second window's value as follows:
 [
  [3, 4],
  [7, 8]
 ]

and so on.
I have tried using numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.
but without any success.
also it is important to use numpy or any other efficient library since implementing this code with a python for-loop is too expensive for that operation.

What operation? Please give an example for loop demonstrating what you want to do. Are m and n always divisible by k? Is the size 3 dimension relevant?

calculate mean over the pixel values

Without overlap, reshape (and possibly transpose) should be enough.  But np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view is easier (and safer) to use than as_strided.  Just using a slice to select the non-overlapping subarrays.

@hpaulj, care to demonstrate?

Does your sliding window overlap?

What you want is often called "mean pooling" in the context of machine learning. how to perform max/mean pooling on a 2d array using numpy

This question is closer to what you're asking for, but is more work to implement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070349/using-numpy-stride-tricks-to-get-non-overlapping-array-blocks

I adapted one of the examples from the first link to your problem: from skimage.measure import block_reduce; block_reduce(A2, func=np.mean, block_size=(2, 2)). If doing this on a 3D array, and you want to avoid pooling on the last axis, you can instead do block_reduce(A2, func=np.mean, block_size=(2, 2, 1))

You still have to consider a scenario where the strides is not equal to the kernel size. ie you have overlaps. Consider functions like shown above, also consider AveragePooling from keras and pytorch

this is less of a "sliding window" and more of a tiling situation.

@ChristophRackwitz I was not familiar with this term, but actually yes

Ignoring the third dimension, since it doesn't seem to enter the problem, how about:
# Generate array of size (m*k, n*k)
# my m, n are your m, n divided by k
m, n = 2, 4
k = 3
x = np.arange(m*n*k*k).reshape((m*k, n*k))
# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
#        [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
#        [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
#        [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47],
#        [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
#        [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71]])

# Calculate means of each block
y = x.reshape((m, k, n, k))
z = np.moveaxis(y, -3, -2)  # now shape is (m, n, k, k) 
np.mean(z, axis=(-2, -1))  # take mean over last two axes
# or just np.mean(y, axis=(-3, -1)) 
# array([[13., 16., 19., 22.],
#        [49., 52., 55., 58.]])

To preserve the third dimension and do the calculations on each color channel separately, just move it out of the way at the beginning (e.g. to axis 0), then move it back at the end.
If the number of rows and/or columns are not divisible by k, you could pad the array with some sentinel value that doesn't appear in the data (e.g. nan) until the number of rows/columns are divisible by k. Then, take the means in some way that ignores the sentinel values (e.g. nanmean). (Alternatively, split off the remainder rows/columns, handle them separately, and combine the results.)
There might be something in scipy.ndimage or scikit-image that will do this in one line. I tried zoom, but didn't find a magic combination of settings that gave the desired result.

Would np.mean(z, axis=(1, -1)) work without the moveaxis step?

In [374]: win = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr,(2,2))

In [375]: win.shape
Out[375]: (3, 3, 2, 2)

taking every other, non-overlapping window:
In [376]: win[::2,::2]
Out[376]: 
array([[[[ 1,  2],
         [ 5,  6]],

        [[ 3,  4],
         [ 7,  8]]],


       [[[ 9, 10],
         [13, 14]],

        [[11, 12],
         [15, 16]]]])

The reshape alternative:
In [378]: arr.reshape(2,2,2,2).transpose(0,2,1,3)
Out[378]: 
array([[[[ 1,  2],
         [ 5,  6]],

        [[ 3,  4],
         [ 7,  8]]],


       [[[ 9, 10],
         [13, 14]],

        [[11, 12],
         [15, 16]]]])


Here is a tensorflow solution:
from tensorflow.keras.layers import AveragePooling2D
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7 ,8],[9, 10, 11, 12],[13, 14, 15, 16]])
y = x.reshape(1,*x.shape, 1).astype(float) # you need 4d

AveragePooling2D(2, 2)(y).numpy().squeeze()
array([[ 3.5,  5.5],
       [11.5, 13.5]], dtype=float32)


AveragePooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (1,1))(y).numpy().squeeze() 
array([[ 3.5,  4.5,  5.5],
       [ 7.5,  8.5,  9.5],
       [11.5, 12.5, 13.5]], dtype=float32)


